# CRM Odata url 5000 Row limitation + PowerBI

Tags: odata, dynamics-crm, powerbi, dynamics-crm-online, powerbi-datasource

I am working on a POC to explore PowerBI RLS. While working on the POC, I found that the CRM ODATA end point is only returning first 5000 records and it returns a next link with paging cookie.

My Query is, How can we utilize this mechanism to get all the data (approx 32000 Rows) into a single Table in PowerBI. Is there an out of the box functionality to get all data.

PowerBI does not provide me with much options while using the Web Connector for CRM.

I have tried to look at following url's :
http://crmchap.co.uk/powerbi-deep-dive-using-the-web-api-to-query-dynamics-crm365-for-enterprise/

https://us.hitachi-solutions.com/blog/fast-vs-furious-powerbi-dynamics-crm-avoid-common-mistake-watch-data-fly/

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/service-connect-to-microsoft-dynamics-crm

http://www.cloudfronts.com/issue-faces-retrieving-5000-records-using-web-api/

https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Desktop/Online-Service-Functionality-in-Power-BI/td-p/101864

https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Desktop/Online-Service-Functionality-in-Power-BI/td-p/101864

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So The limitation is just at Odata feed end in browser or via code.
Latest release of powerbi brings in all the data. They are probably using the same next and previous link which comes at the end of 5000 rows.